# How to get user input on same line instead of next line

Tags: java

Newbie here, took up Java about a week ago and trying to learn as much as I can, so help is most definitely appreciated.

As practice I am writing up an interactive story where the user can pick the next outcome. My question is how can I receive user input on the same line?

As you can see in the code, the User can choose choice 1 or choice 2 but when I run the program the user has to skip a line to be able to choose option 2.

How can I make it so the system receives input on the very first line regardless of what number the user picks.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner choices = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("");
    String line1 = "You suddenly awaken and find yourself in a pitch black room with the only source of light being the distinct lines of what you can only imagine is a door...You attempt to stand but realize your are bound to a chair by your hands and feet";
    System.out.println(line1);
    System.out.println("");
    String line2 = "Do you: (Type number of corresponding choice)";
    System.out.println(line2);
    String choice1 = "1. Call out for help";
    String choice2 = "2. Try to wiggle your way to the supposed door";
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println(choice1);
    System.out.println(choice2);
    if (choices.nextInt() == 1)
    System.out.println("You call out for help but to no avail, no one responds and all you hear is the deafening sound of silence");
    if (choices.nextInt() == 2)
    System.out.println("You start to build some momentum by swinging to and fro in the chair you are bound to and are able to make it to the door!");
```

Comment: declare ```int choice = choices.nextInt();``` then use ```if(choice == 1){} else if(choice == 2){]``` the way you have it now is asking for input twice when it should only ask once. Then se ```if{} else{}``` to check for the input

Comment: Whoever closed the post definitely does not like helping new contributers to Stack Overflow.... didn't read the question/post clearly enough to understand your problem